# integrating html design to servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, servlets

I have a working servlet code, which processes some command prompt commands and I have an editor code written in html, now I want to add this html file to servlet. How do I do it? tried moving the html file to WEB-INF.

I've looked into this link on [How to integrate HTML design into Servlet?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=153)  but everything seems damn cumbersome as I have a very large html file.

Any other fixes?

Comment: Html code should not be merged in servlet. As you've mentioned if the html file is large it will be very difficult to manage your servlet. Even breaks the mvc design pattern. There is no workaround for your requirement. Any reason you want to do this?

Comment: this HTML file should be the front end for the servlet, I've designed to invoke the servlet from the HTML file how to make it other way round?

Comment: So you want to generate your html from servlet. is it?

Comment: No, I want html design to be the frontend of the servlet.

Comment: Use JSP or a template mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your editor.html contains only static JS, CSS and HTML (you don't depend on the data provided by your servlet), you can simply forward your servlet into JSP and include your html page from it using

`<%@ include file="editor.html" %>`

Comment: Yes, my editor contains only static things, where should I put that command? and in which package should I place my editor.html? can you please elaborate?

Comment: It depends what you want to do :) If the response is prepared and written completely by your servlet, you don't need JSP nor the include directive. You only need to read the file, for example by: `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/editor.html");` and than write it to the output stream. You should consider caching as well. If your application is following the MVC paradigm, that is the servlet is only preparing data and the view is rendering the response, than put the include directive into forwarded JSP.